# How do I put all of the music in my iTunes library (12.2) onto my iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac

Really frustrated with iTunes -- How the heck do I add the music in my iTunes library to my iPhone?

I'm a power user and I've been using iTunes and iPods since the beginning.

I'm going on a road trip tomorrow morning and I want to sync my iPhone 6 with my iTunes library -- just put all 15 GB of music on my iPhone so I can listen to it in the car.

Last week I installed iTunes 12.2 and I signed up for Apple Music.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to sync my 15 GB iTunes library to my iPhone so I can use it like an iPod.  I don't want to stream music from Apple Music while I'm on the road, that requires the cellular network which is unreliable and also costs me tons of money in data fees.

Please help!!

Comment: You might find this helpful: [Syncing Music Locally to iPhone with Apple Music/iOS 8.4/iTunes 12.2](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3bouao/syncing_music_locally_to_iphone_with_apple/)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have your 'entire Music Library' downloaded on your Mac. This seems like a simple case.

1. Plug your iPhone into your Mac.
2. Open iTunes
3. Tap the iPhone icon
4. Under the "Settings" section header, click "Music"
5. Click the checkboxes "Sync Music" and "Sync Entire music library"
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: It turns out, "Sync Music" was not a visible option because "Apple Music" and/or "iCloud Music" were active on either (1) my iPhone, (2) iTunes, or (3) my Mac.  Honestly, this stuff is getting way to complex (maybe I'll go back to 8-track tapes).

Answer (score 0):

When you use Apple Music it automatically turns on iCloud Music Library, which lets you add Apple Music tracks to your "My Music" playlist (enabled by Apple Music). This is similar but not completely the same to iTunes Match, so it strips the ability for you to sync your music manually.

If you have your existing music backed up, turn off iCloud Music Library in Settings > Music > iCloud Music Library on your iPhone. This will delete any Apple Music tracks you may have added to your My Music playlist. Then, sync your music over, and if you still want to use iCloud Music Library, turn it back on again. This is what user3439894 posted in his comment to your question.